# Выделить жирным все вхождения искомой подстроки PHP

Tags: php

необходимо сделать: при выводе содержимого текущего каталога (и в CLI режиме, и в веб-режиме) подсветить жирным все вхождения искомой подстроки в именах файлов и директорий.
веб-режиме я реализовал это так

```
preg_replace(".$serchname.", "<b>$0</b>", $file)
```

а как сделать это в командной строке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Жирным не получится, сделайте просто подсветку

```
<?php 
    echo "some text \033[1mLight\033[0m enother text\n";
?>
```

**update**.

Давайте вместе порассуждаем.

Вам необходимо вывести `форматированный` текст в различные, скажем так, подсистемы отображения информации: браузеры, консоли (linux/bash, cmd, PowerShell, etc). Все эти "подсистемы" имеют свое собственное представление о форматировании. Браузеры - html тэги, консоли - некий набор спецсимволов, Microsoft Word - какой-то свой набор тэгов.

В результате у нас проблема - html тэги будут восприняты только браузерами, спец.символы (причем разные) - консолями и т.д.

Значит надо, либо заставить все подсистемы вывода одинаково интерпретировать разметку текста, либо в коде писать свой вывод в расчете на все подсистемы, в которых надо отображать текст.

Другими словами, либо заставить все консоли интерпретировать `<b>` как **жирный тескт**, либо заставить все браузеры интерпретировать некий `\033[1m` как тот же самый жирный.

Или написать, как вы говорите, тот самый костыль.

Comment: это конечно выход, но костыль, ТЗ стоит другое

Comment: @VolkovVD Добавил апдейт.